# ngChange not working inside modal?

Tags: angularjs

I have this modal:

```
<!--Modal-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="usernameModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Welcome</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span style="font-size: large;color:#d9534f;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></span>
            <input ng-change="checkUsername()" ng-model="msg.name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-class="startButton" class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

And I'm trying to fire an event when something get changed , this is my angular code:

```
$scope.checkUsername = function () {
    alert("test");
};
```

`ngKeydown`, `ngKeypress` and `ngKeyup` also didn't work, does anyone know if those directives are removed?

---

**EDIT**:

In [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3AL3gCLKYqLyvYKv8qe) is all works perfectly outside a modal.

Comment: Any errors? Where is your controller defined in the html?

Comment: No errors, but I think it's something with the controller

Comment: there are no controller in html

Comment: Yes, this line fixed it for me: `controller: 'modalCtrl'`.

Comment: Your function should be in same controller where your are loading model

Comment: updated the working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/9QgTQKuTtuL4at44fgmX?p=preview

Comment: @vpsingh016 Perfect! You can make an answers if you want.

Comment: Do you use modal from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ? Notice that you need separate controller for modal `ModalInstanceCtrl`